# Cannot Free Memory in C - Dynamic Struct and array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc, free

I have been trying to free the memory of my program for the past 2 days. For some reason, I can never fully free. I have a loop and it mallocs inside it twice:

```
struct entry
{
  int utf8length;
  char * utf8text;

};

for( int i = 0; i < constant_pool_count; i++ )
{
      ent = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
      if(ent==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed malloc, Exiting the program \n");
        exit(-1);
       }
      ent->utf8length = sizeOfUtf;
      carr = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfUtf + 1);
      if(carr==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed malloc, Exiting the program \n");
        exit(-1);
      }
       //More code

}
```

How am I supposed to free them?

Comment: inside the _for_ just `free(ent); free(carr);`, if after the _for_ that means you need to memorize their addresses. Probably `ent->utf8text = carr;` is missing too ?

Comment: For each `ent` and `carr` that you allocate inside the loop, call `free(ent)` and `free(carr)`.  Your posted code is incomplete so it's not clear how you're storing the pointers, so not much more can be said.   If you're saving them someplace, then you need to traverse those data structures to get the pointers back.

Answer (score 0):

In the code after this fragment, you probably have:

```
ent->utf8text = carr;
```

You would free each `struct entry` in 2 steps:

```
free(ent->utf8text);
free(ent);
```

Note that this code is slightly inconsistent: `malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfUtf + 1);`. The size is correct because `sizeof(char)` is `1`, but for consistency it should either read:

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * (sizeOfUtf + 1));
```

Or

```
malloc(sizeOfUtf + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

first case, they are freed in the loop:

```
struct entry
{
  int utf8length;
  char * utf8text;

};

...

for( int i = 0; i < constant_pool_count; i++ )
{
      struct entry * ent;
      char * carr;

      ent = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
      if(ent==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed malloc, Exiting the program \n");
        exit(-1);
       }
      ent->utf8length = sizeOfUtf;
      carr = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfUtf + 1);
      if(carr==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed malloc, Exiting the program \n");
        exit(-1);
      }

      ent->utf8text = carr; // I suppose

      //More code

      free(ent->utf8text);
      free(ent);
}
```

second case, you need them out of the loop then you free them

```
struct entry
{
  int utf8length;
  char * utf8text;

};

...

struct entry * all[constant_pool_count];

for( int i = 0; i < constant_pool_count; i++ )
{
      struct entry * ent;
      char * carr;

      ent = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
      if(ent==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed malloc, Exiting the program \n");
        exit(-1);
       }
      ent->utf8length = sizeOfUtf;
      carr = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfUtf + 1);
      if(carr==NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed malloc, Exiting the program \n");
        exit(-1);
      }

      ent->utf8text = carr; // I suppose
      all[i] = ent;

      //More code
}

... some code

// free them

for( int i = 0; i < constant_pool_count; i++ )
{
   free (all[i]->utf8text);
   free (all[i]);
   // may be "all[i] = NULL;" if useful ?
}
```